# How to get before and after insert unique ID from output clause while inserting

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How can one get before and after insert unique ID from output clause while inserting?

For example: I have a table named A, I need to copy some of the records via

> [insert into select statement](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp)

and I need to get old unique id and new unique id in to a temp table using

> [OUTPUT Clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx)

This means I need to get return type as **before insert unique identifier** and **after inert unique identifier**. For that, I tried using below query as

```
    DECLARE @MyTableVar TABLE 
  ( 
     newid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, 
     oldid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER 
  ); 
INSERT A (name, description) 
output inserted.guid, 
       d.guid 
INTO @MyTableVar 
SELECT name, description
FROM   A d 
WHERE  deptID = 550; 
SELECT * 
FROM   @MyTableVar
```

But I am not able to get **d.guid** in **output clause**. Please correct me if there are any other options to get before and after insert unique id as output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
@@IDENTITY
```

to get after insert unique id as output.

Comment: he is not asking about identity

Answer (score 0):

You should use column names from table.In your case ,you are using Inserted.Guid which should throw syntax error

```
create table tt
(
id varchar(300) default newid()
)

declare @t table
(
id varchar(300)
)

insert into tt
output inserted.* into @t
default values

select * from @t
```

Comment: By giving "Inserted.Guid", i was able to get new inserted guid. But i was not able to get old guid id("d.guid"), Reason for that was, "d.guid" was not under output clause scope and i was not able to get solution with this answer.